# Copy property from other type

Tags: typescript

I have a type `Command`

```js
export type Command<
  Type extends string = string,
> = {
  type: Type
}
```

I'm creating a type `Handler` like this:

```js
export type Handler<T extends Command> = {
  type: Pick<T, 'type'>
}
```

The goal is to make sure that the type of the returned `Handler` here is the same as for the command:

```js
export type MyCommand = Command<'MyCommand'>

const MyHandler = (): Handler<MyCommand> => {
  return {
    type: 'MyCommand'
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Pick<MyCommand, "type">'.(2322)
```

I've created TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEC2mCGA7AEwB4AoOOAFWVVBmEIGc4GYoBLPAczgF5nWOnADQkAfLzgBvMgmoAuStRIBfEiVCRYslHAAS%20AgBtgUIhTi16BJhmwHxfaeSQoFABTYBjANZmhcAHIXYADRFTUNaHhguABZRFtcQglEgyIA%20NTCULVPCDwWOMR9QmMoCQAKAEoFEqMTIkysJIIHcSc4KGAYAFcoPCkZZ3lAprtsmVVlIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pick<T, K>` creates an object type that contains the properties specified in `K`. So `Pick<MyCommand, 'type'>` is actually `{ type: 'MyCommand' }`

If you just want the type of a property in another type use an index accessed type `T[K]`

```
export type Command<
  Type extends string = string,
> = {
  type: Type
}

export type Handler<T extends Command> = {
  type: T['type']
}

export type MyCommand = Command<'MyCommand'>

const MyHandler = (): Handler<MyCommand> => {
  return {
    type: 'MyCommand'
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEC2mCGA7AEwB4AoOOAFWVVBmEIGc4GYoBLPAczgF5nWOnADQkAfLzgBvMgmoAuStRIBfEiVCRYslHAAS+AgBtgUIhTi16BJhmwHxfaeSQoFFANoByF8E8BdFTUNaHgfOABZRFtcQglogyJPSPjCT1E1AGMIPBYIxH1CYygJAAoASgUCoxMiZKwYggdxJzgoYBgAVyg8KRlneTgkqPqDTxlVZSA)

Answer (score 1):

You can infer `Type` generic type from Command inside Handler like this:

```js
export type Handler<T> = T extends Command<infer Type> 
  ? {type: Type} 
  : never;
```

Following description is how *I* understand inference in this case.

Here we have ternary type where we check that `T` in fact extends `Command`. If it doesn't extends `Command`, we return `never`, as it should never happen. But if it does, we infer (get type) value of `Command` generic and put it into some kind of type variable `Type`. Then we return `{type: Type}` as a value of our Handler.